# Two foreach loops into one in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

Given the following:

```
$arrayone = array('Title one', 'Title two');
$arraytwo = array('Content one', 'Content two');
```

How would I go about out putting the following:

```
<h2>Title one</h2>
<p>content one</p>

<h2>Title two</h2>
<p>content two</p>
```

I could do a nested foreach like so:

```
foreach ($arrayone as $key => $value) {
    echo "<h4>$value</h4>";
    foreach ($arraytwo as $keysub => $valuesub) {
        # code...
        if($keysub === $key) {
            echo "<p>$valuesub</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine, but I think it's not the most efficient way since it's going through the second array for each item in the first... It doesn't seem right.

How to make it more efficient?

Comment: Since you are not using associative arrays, the preferred method would be a `for` loop, which has the benefit of less memory overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sensible data structure:

```
$content = array_map(null, $arrayone, $arraytwo);

foreach ($content as $entry) {
    printf('<h2>%s</h2>', $entry[0]);
    printf('<p>%s</p>', $entry[1]);
}
```

Or even:

```
$content = array_combine($arrayone, $arraytwo);

foreach ($content as $title => $body) {
    printf('<h2>%s</h2>', $title);
    printf('<p>%s</p>', $body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use one for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titlesArray); $i++) {
    echo "<h1>".$titlesArray[$i]."<h1>";
    echo "<p>".$paragraphsArray[$i]."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've correctly set up the arrays to always have the same order and number of items:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayone); $i++) {
  echo "<h4>{$arrayone[$i]}</h4>";
  echo "<p>{$arraytwo[$i]}</p>";
}
```

You'd be better off with a more sensible array format, though:

```
$array = [
  ['title' => 'Title one', 'content' => 'Content one'],
  ['title' => 'Title two', 'content' => 'Content two'],
];
```

Comment: ahhhhh I never knew i could do that it does seem a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Since all of the obvious answers have already been posted, here is just another way to do it

```
foreach (array_combine($arrayone, $arraytwo) as $title => $content) {
    printf('<h2>%s</h2><p>%s</p>', $title, $content);
}
```